# Flex value object has null properties in java

Tags: java, apache-flex, spring, blazeds

I have a simple service I have created using Spring-Flex 1.5. When I pass data from flex to java the value object is null on the java end. I have tested and debugged as much as I possibly could and I find not find a reason for this.

I have tried to narrow the possibilities down as much as I could. So instead of doing anything with my data, I simply just return the passed in value object.

I have verified that I am able to hit the service and the service does return data by creating the test(String dataString) method in my service. This method does return the correct result.

This is the data that I am sending to java:

```
(UserAccount)#0
InstanceID = 1
IsLoggedIn = false
IsVisible = false
UserID = NaN
UserName = "user123"
UserPass = "password"
UserStatus = true
UserTypeID = 1
```

This is what I am receiving back:

```
(UserAccount)#0
InstanceID = NaN
IsLoggedIn = false
IsVisible = false
UserID = NaN
UserName = (null)
UserPass = (null)
UserStatus = false
UserTypeID = NaN
```

This is the output I see in my log4j log file

```
723011 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-28] DEBUG com.rottmanj.services.user.UserAccountService  - com.rottmanj.domain.user.UserAccount@5994a1e9
.
```

Actionscript code:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;
                    import com.rottmanj.domain.user;        

        private function sendVO():void
        {
            var vo:UserAccount = new UserAccount();
            vo.UserName = 'user123';
            vo.UserPass = 'password';
            vo.UserStatus = true;
            vo.IsLoggedIn = false;
            vo.IsVisible = false;
            vo.UserTypeID = 1;
            vo.InstanceID = 1;              
            dBug.text = ObjectUtil.toString(vo);                
            ro.save(vo);                
        }

        private function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            dBug.text = dBug.text + ObjectUtil.toString(event.result);
        }

        private function faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
        {
            dBug.text = dBug.text + ObjectUtil.toString(event.fault);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Actionscript VO:

```
[Bindable]
[RemoteClass(alias="com.rottmanj.domain.user.UserAccount")]
public class UserAccount
{ (setters/getters)...}
```

Java Service:

```
@Service
@RemotingDestination
public class UserAccountService {

private UserAccountDAO dao = null;
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserAccountService.class);

@Autowired
public void setDao(UserAccountDAO dao)
{
    this.dao = dao;
}

@RemotingInclude
public UserAccount save(UserAccount dataObject)
{
    logger.debug(dataObject.toString());        
    return dataObject;
}

@RemotingInclude
public String test(String dataString)
{
    logger.debug(dataString.toString()); 
    return "This is a Test for " + dataString;
}
}
```

Comment: Please post the java UserAccount class.

Comment: Just to be sure: UserAccount.java resides in package `com.rottmanj.domain.user`?

Comment: Here is the UserAccount.java file  
http://pastebin.com/cUVndzFW
This is this actionscript value object
http://pastebin.com/1a3TvaT3

Comment: I got this figured out, my properties in my AS value object were not named correctly.

Comment: @rottmanj You should post that as an answer so this doesn't remain open.